# Knex.js PostgreSQL how to change transaction isolation level?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

This doesn't seem to be covered in [Knex.js docs](http://knexjs.org/). Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use with transaction options, like:

```js
   this.knex.transaction(async (trx) => { ... }, { isolationLevel: 'repeatable read' });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect it to be a raw SQL statement.  [Syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-transaction.html)

```
knex.schema.raw('set transaction isolation level serializable;')
```

This setting persists for the current session. That means you might have to change it to something else for other queries in the same session.